# Does Discussions Beta have its own RSS feed for tags?

Tags: support, discussions-space, rss

I'm trying to find if there is a Discussions-specific RSS feed like there is for questions. I would like to find and respond to items with a particular tag or two.

Is this possible?

Comment: I've swapped this over to being tagged with [[tag:support]], since it's asking for whether the feature exists– if you're looking to _request_ a feature, you should reword your post to ask for it more explicitly.

Comment: @AugustoVasques  I believe when I tried to pick that tag I wound up with SO complaining that it was too much like another tag.   It would only really let me pick the longer discussion-space option as I recall

Comment: @LhasaDad Did you try to add the tag [discussions] instead, maybe? The error you got should only happen when trying to create a tag, and [meta-tag:discussion] already exists - but note that it refers to the actual act of discussing things on Meta, not for the "Discussions" feature (you can thank whoever came up with the feature for that confusion).